# Did anyone cross over to the mirror universe to find a loved one?

Tags: star-trek, mirror-universe

From [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mirror_universe):

> the Federation was fighting a costly war at the time they learned of the mirror universe and Starfleet admiralty was afraid of desperate attempts to reunite with loved ones...

It seems like an interesting plot, but I don't think it's ever been done in any iteration of Star Trek. Was it done in any of the novels?

Comment: The article lists the following Discovery episodes as the inspiration for that paragraph; (DIS: "Vaulting Ambition", "The War Without, The War Within")

Comment: Answers to some other question here on SO established that mirror-Kira has a narcissistic personality disorder and likes to meet herself (or at least mirror-self). Not sure if that matches your idea of a "loved one".

Comment: @EikePierstorff - I'm the one that asked about Mirror Kira being in love with her prime self. What I was looking for is, you lost a loved one so go into the mirror universe to bring their counterpart back to your universe, so you can love them. Obviously, it work right away, but it might be fun to watch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Isn't that exactly what

> Captain Lorca

does in Discovery? He was obsessed with

> Burnham

and manipulated events so that they would return to the mirror universe together.

Answer (score 12):

There's at least two instances in Deep Space Nine,  at least sort of.

In  Through The Looking Glass, Sisko-prime was brought to the mirror universe in order to speak to his late wife's counterpart. He was able to use his influence as her husband's counterpart to persuade her to switch sides and join the rebellion.

[Memory Alpha summary.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Through_the_Looking_Glass_(episode))

> In the "mirror universe," Sisko must persuade the alternate version of his dead wife to join the Terran Rebels, or he will watch her die a second time.

In the episode Resurrection,  the mirror counterpart of Kira's dead lover  arrives in the prime universe. Again, this is a plot to use his influence to persuade her.

[Memory Alpha summary](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Resurrection_(episode))

> An alternate version of Vedek Bareil arrives from the "Mirror Universe" seeking refuge.

Comment: I think you have the causality of Sisko's situation backwards with regard to the question. Sisko didn't go to the mirror universe to seek to reconnect with a dead loved one, he was brought there against his will, and ended up using her connection to him to aid the rebellion. If actually went to the mirror universe out of a desire for connection to a loved one, it's Jake Sisko who went to reconnect with his mother.

Comment: I know, that's why I qualified it with 'sort of' Basically, Sisko went to the mirror universe to reconnect with his dead wife. It wasn't his own idea, and the intent was to influence her, rather than romance, but it still fits the question, sort of.

Comment: @Pete You're still right. He went there, and the purpose was reconnection. It wasn't his purpose and he didn't go voluntarily, but, strictly speaking, it's a perfect fit.

Answer (score -3):

I think it may have been a parallel universe instead of the mirror one, but in Voyager, Naomi Wildman dies shortly after being born and then another version of her is brought over from the other dimension.

Comment: That wasn't the Mirror Universe.

Comment: Note the absence of a tiny goatee on baby Naomi